# Array insertion in a for loop C coding

Tags: c, controller, signal-processing, moving-average

```
    for(t=0; t<=1; t+=1e-4)
    {
        input [n] = 2 + sin(w*t);
    }
```

Hi I am new to C coding. I'm trying to program a Moving Average filter to be used in DSP controller to continuously calculate average of a waveform.

In this step, I would like to sample data from a sine wave with a step-size of 1e-4, and save them into an buffer. The buffer size should be 1000. But in this case, "t" is not an integer, so how can I be able to do that? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You need to post more code, ideally the [mcve]. Also the problem is not clear.

Comment: `t` is not an integer ? Well you can cast it `(int) t` or `Convert.ToInt16(t)` but i think you would want to multiply it before... What is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use floating point values as loop indices. Use integers:

```
double t = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
    t = i / 1000.0;
    input[i] = 2.0 + sin(w * t);
}
```

Comment: for(array_size = 0; array_size < 1000; array_size ++)
    {
        input[array_size] = 2.0 + sin(w * t);
        t += 1e-4;
   
    } This one actually works. When t=i/1000; each input element is 2.0, which is not right. Thanks very much for your help!!!

Comment: I originally wrote it with `t += 1e-4;`, but I was concerned about error accumulation, so I changed it to `t = i / 1000.0;`, or at least I thought I did? Did I forget the `.0`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use **microseconds** so you can sample with integer numbers. You just have to adjust the formula so the result is in concordance.